# Add action to back button

Tags: android

I have an overlay view added to the content view in my app.

I want to add an action to the back button to remove this overlay view before then having the default back button functionality.

What would be the best way to go about this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My solution to this scenario is to make a global indicator of where the user is in the application.

For example, consider this (straight from my current project):

```
//...
private boolean mInSettingsMode;
//...

// The button's onclick method.
public void onSettingsButtonClick(View v) {
    mInSettingsMode = true;
    // Initialize view stuff.
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        if (mInSettingsMode) {
            mInSettingsMode = false;
            resetToNormalView();
            return true;
        } else {
            return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
        }
    }       
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: cool thanks, I've done that. :) Although I've rewritten the method: `if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && mInSettingsMode) {` so I only have the one `return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);` statement. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2):

You should implement the onKeyDown() method and check if the keyCode is back. If yes, you can do anything you want.

Hope this helps!

Comment: onKeyDown... is that an activity method?

Comment: Yeap it is a method of the Activity which you should override

Answer (score 1):

You should override [`onBackPressed()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed%28%29) :

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    // Add your code here

    // Then call the parent constructor to have the default button functionality
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: This is only android 2.0 and above unfortunately. Although I guess with the advent of Android 4.0 its probably best to stop supporting 1.6.

Comment: I agree, Android 1.6 now represents only 1.3% of the market share (http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html) and it is generally a huge waste of time to try to support it.